# Global formatting options for floating point numbers

Tags: c++, c++11

I know it is *not* possible to overload (stream) operators for primitive types as follows:

```
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream &stream, const double s) {
    stream << std::scientific << std::showpos << std::setprecision(15) << std::to_string(s);
    return stream;
}
```

What is the preferred way for defining global formatting options for primitive types? Note that I want to apply the formatting to any kind of output stream, not only specific streams like `std::cout`. C++11 solutions are welcome. Any hints?

Comment: You could just define a manipulator that applies the desired options. Explicit is good, implicit is bad. Roughly.

Comment: You shouldn't (want to) do that, even if it were possible. It would make your code harder to comprehend and maintain.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Could you be more explicit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overloading streams is a bad idea, but you can wrap them. If you want to do a special but common pre/post-processing, define a custom (templated) class that has a stream as member (maybe affected in constructor), and delegates actual io to that stream after preprocessing input and/or do some post-processing after.

```
class Printer {
    ostream &ost;

    Printer(ostream& st): ost(st) {
        // other initializations ...
    }

    Printer& operator << (double d) {
        ost << std::scientific << std::showpos << std::setprecision(15) << std::to_string(s);
        return *this;
    }
    // others: ostream conversion, other processing...
}
```

Comment: you should specify why *overloading streams is a bad idea*.

Comment: @Walter: because as many of the Standard Library classes, they were not designed to be overloaded (no virtual destructors, no way to have standard streams implement you custom class)

Answer (score 5):

You could define your own manipulator for setting up the stream formatters. Your manipulator must conform to the format expected by the `<<` operator:

```
basic_ostream& operator<<(
    std::basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>& (*func)(std::basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>&) );
```

So for instance:

```
template <class Char>
basic_ostream<Char>& format_double(basic_ostream<Char>& stream) {
    return stream << std::scientific 
                  << std::showpos 
                  << std::setprecision(15);
}
```

Then just do:

```
cout << format_double << 2.0;
```

**References**

- [<< operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) specially case (9)

**Notes**

There are two format for manipulators, one takes a `ios_base` as argument and the other a `basic_ostream`. You must use the later because it is not specified what is the return value of `setprecision(int)`. For instance, my compiler (gcc-4.9) returns a struct `_Setprecision` holding the integer and defines a specific operator `<<` for this struct and `basic_ostream`.

Comment: exactly what I was just going to say! +1

Comment: Good suggestion, but I bet that one would keep forgetting the manipulator at least at some places in the code (this holds particularly true if you are working in a team) and end up having output formatted differently. In some applications, it is desirable to have floating point numbers always formatted in the same way.

Answer (score 2):

The formatting of the numeric types (integers and floating point numbers) can be modified by making sure streams are using a different `std::locale`. This facility *can* be used to effect the formatting of all streams which are created *after* the global `std::locale` is set. Existing streams can also be made to use this modified `std::locale` by `imbue()`ing.

An example could look something like this:

```
class special_num_put
    : public std::num_put<char> {
    virtual iter_type do_put(iter_type it, ios_base& fmt,
                             char_type fill, double v) const {
        fmt.precision(15);
        fmt.setf(std::ios_base::showpos);
        fmt.setf(std::ios_base::scientific, std::ios_base::floatfield);
        return this->std::num_put<char>::do_put(it, fmt, fill, v);
    }
    // likewise for all of the other numeric types
};

int main() {
    std::locale::global(std::locale(std::locale(), new special_num_put));
    std::cout.imbue(std::locale()); // deal with existing stream
    // likewise for all other preexisting streams
}
```

Note that I agree with the comment made earlier that you should **not** want to do anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on [fjardon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32945115/1023390), you may create a default format for any type you want using a template, such that

```
cout << formatted(2.0) << ' ' << formatted(1.4,6) << ' ' << formatted(2.3f)
```

uses different precisions etc. This could be implemented via

```
namespace io_formatting {
  template<typename Tp>
  struct manipulator
  {
    Tp  val;
    int prec;
    manipulator(Tp x, int p=std::numeric_limits<Tp>::digits10)
    : val(x), prec(p) {}        
  };
  template<typename X>
  inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&o, manipulator<X> const&m)
  {
    return o << std::scientific 
             << std::showpos 
             << std::setprecision(m.prec)
             << m.val;
  }
}
template<typename Tp>
io_formatting::manipulator<Tp> formatted(Tp x) { return {x}; }
template<typename Tp>
io_formatting::manipulator<Tp> formatted(Tp x, int p) { return {x,p}; }
```

You can use specialisation and/or SFINAE to differentiate between different types (floating-point, integral, complex ...).

Comment: This is a completely different answer than fjardon's. This follows more the "pretty-printer" approach than the manipulator concept.